# Leaflet marker popup not rendering

Tags: popup, leaflet, jinja2, markers

[image]I have markers in a list, I am trying to read markers in the list from my database to show pop up information but it's not working. I am using jinja to print the list from python into html, i just get an internal server error message. I am using oracle and cgi-bin

```
  var markers= L.markerClusterGroup({

   });

{% for item in markers %}


var marker{{ item[0] }} = L.marker({{ item[3:] }});
var popup{{ item[0] }} = $('<div />');
popup{{ item[0] }}.html("<br>{{ item[1] }}<br>&pound{{ item[2] }<br<button>Run to this place</button>");
markers.addLayer(marker{{ item[0] }}.bindPopup(popup{{ item[0] }}[0]));
map.addLayer(markers)
  {% endfor %}
```

Comment: You should probably include the error message in your question.

Comment: @ghybs it's an internal server error message